# Custom types and their usage

Tags: haskell

Hello I have 3 custom types and then type created with these 3 types.

```
type Name = String
type Age = Int
type Semester = Int
type Student = (Name, Age, Semester)
```

I need to create function which takes student and returns his name
i have created this but it doesn't work.

```
getName :: Student -> Name:
getName (name_, age_, semester_) = name_
```

Comment: You don't have custom types; you have type aliases. Your function looks fine; what exactly doesn't work? How are you calling the function?

Comment: You have a stray `:` after your function signature.

Comment: At the end of the first line `Name:` should be `Name`. The rest looks fine.

Comment: are we sure it's a typo? maybe they thought that's the way to write it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
getName :: Student -> Name
getName (name_, age_, semester_) = name_
```

There shouldn't be any `:` or anything else in the end of the signature.

First line contains the signature by itself. Then go the lines with the definition. The type alias is `Name`, not `Name:`, so that's what should be used.

Comment: yeah i had typo in it and now it works just fine

Comment: if it's a typo, I shouldn't have answered. ;) :) happy trails! :)